PHP: something wrong with this closure syntax?
I'm following along an old book and am on an exercise using function_exists
here's the code for the exercise
<?php
    function tagWrap($tag, $txt, $func = "") {
        if ((!empty($txt)) && (function_exists($func))) {
            $txt = $func($txt);
            return "<$tag>$txt</$tag>\n";
        }
    }

    function underline($txt) {
        return "<u>$txt</u>";
    }

    echo tagWrap('b', 'make me bold');
    echo tagWrap('i', 'underline me too', "underline");
    echo tagWrap('i', 'make me italic and quote me',
        create_function("$txt", "return \"&quot;$txt&quot;\";"));
?>

As expected, the first function call shows nothing because there's no function in the args, and the second shows correctly since the underline function is defined, issue is with the third call with the closure: it's supposed to show the text but it doesn't.
At first i thought to myself "that's silly, i'm ceating a function but am passing return as a string", but messing with it just left my IDE screaming at me so i guess PHP does work like that, so i've been messing around with '' "" and `` for a while now but there's no way for the third function call to show output.
Am i creating the closure wrong or is this a simple syntax issue when passing the strings?

create_function() is obsolete. It was deprecated in 7.2 and removed in 8.0.

The argument to function_exists() must be a function name, not a closure.

I think you're looking for is_callable(), not function_exists(). https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php

I'm literally copying the exercise from the book (it's Sam's teach yourself PHP from like 2003) and the whole exercise is to make the user aware of function_exists(), so i assumed it'd be alright, but i', like Jon Snow with PHP. I've already adapted the syntax for the closure, i'll now try with is_callable()

Get yourself a newer book. PHP has changed significantly in 20 years.

@Anacardo consider these working experiments with my rescripting of your code: https://3v4l.org/NQjhg

@mickmackusa this is awesomea and very useful as a reference. Thank you so much

The argument to function_exists() must be a string, which is looked up as a function name. You can't pass a closure to it. The correct test should be is_callable(), it will be true for a function name, an array [object, method_name], or a closure.
Since create_function() is obsolete, you should use an anonymous function or arrow function.
<?php
    function tagWrap($tag, $txt, $func = "") {
        if ((!empty($txt)) && (is_callable($func))) {
            $txt = $func($txt);
            return "<$tag>$txt</$tag>\n";
        }
    }

    function underline($txt) {
        return "<u>$txt</u>";
    }

    echo tagWrap('b', 'make me bold');
    echo tagWrap('i', 'underline me too', "underline");
    echo tagWrap('i', 'make me italic and quote me',
        fn($txt) => , "&quot;$txt&quot;");
?>


Yes sir, it works just fine adapting the closure to the new syntax and using is_callable() instead of function_exists()
Thank you so much, i'll try to find a newer book to keep up with the times.
